# ECDSA SECP256k1 curve - same-r-value-is-used-for-two-different-addresses

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, signature, dsa, secp256k1

Edited: changing the notation according request by fgrieu.

I have prepared 4 transactions for 2 pubkeys with the same r1 and r2.

properties of secp256k1:

```
p = 0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364141   # order of curve
```

It is according to: ecdsa-revealing-the-private-key-from-four-signed-message-two-keys-and-shared-nonces-
link here:  https://billatnapier.medium.com/ecdsa-revealing-the-private-key-from-four-signed-message-two-keys-and-shared-nonces-secp256k1-5758f1258b1d

It should work, but it doesn't.

I put transactions, nonces and privatekeys

Why can I not to take value private1 and private2?

It gives me value 0:
please help

```
privkey1= 74151126465914553719682701372546590912032713247110001383204298192577238294259
privkey2= 65602009300807068992382438511465994464148703102269145684254988072233619429415

nonce1= 113430668354305125354139681412571553637810109882549088741100884487402919060793
nonce2= 88941376982568942091029320764989550225390065895384871037015643141890275775717

signature matches
#transaction from first privkey1

r1= 37172049453198803628923372374682424137153412099188977901809252086397375163174
s1= 36665125934301679295764426496089959157670212057714313825462899262019004181013
h1= 45063904364969322573281122086971579379876583577391310824950725157431863085693

r2= 40974080779974461932858835766108658066940207003253964846620894290420102383124
s3= 88414683103569280491867470526894992004240909646745888824999991880846576153983
h3= 96925863066810859394685400246217607442326685412593308871569663983290139782035

##transaction from second privkey2

r1= 37172049453198803628923372374682424137153412099188977901809252086397375163174
s2= 48387795993880540164497955151292140905876432678370698441361372722465054520609
h2= 70890957235815785946608014568730757332857823983374044998781188028671033610413

r2= 40974080779974461932858835766108658066940207003253964846620894290420102383124
s4= 94479523762013111191490500533227932711756342618388816229238677867942525385058
h4= 88400657509035765824159536685234267382896518494653799783594906135509259195161
```

How to calculate, the above privatekey? if I use link : [Is it possible to decrypt an ECDSA private key if the same nonce is used across different private keys?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/80288/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-an-ecdsa-private-key-if-the-same-nonce-is-used-across?rq=1)

I got result 0 for privkey1 and privkey2.

where is problem?

for another example everything works fine. but in above version is problem.

Comment: Compared to the document you have linked, you have operations 2 and 3 swapped.  Swap those then apply the formula for $x_1$ and $x_2$.  Note that this arithmetic is done $\mod p$, so division by $r_1r_2(s_1s_4-s_2s_3)$ is actually multiplying by the modular inverse of $r_1r_2(s_1s_4-s_2s_3)$ $\mod p$. [moderator addition: the change suggested in this comment is now incorporated in the question by the OP].

Comment: fgrieu: _"With your numbers there is $s_1s_4≡s_2s_3\pmod p$"_. Yes. but there must be solvable. the question is what kind change I must do.? Again: the same r1 and r2 as k1 and k2 (nonce1 and nonce2) used for 2 different privatekeys . the problem is s1s4= s2s3 mod p.  How to change the calculation to take real privatekey1 and privatekey2?

Comment: To those proposing to close as a programming question: that's _not_ what the question is about. It's about a special condition $s_1s_4≡s_2s_3\pmod p$ in the values considered and how that condition makes it impossible to perform the calculation in the references. A reason I see to perhaps close the question is that this condition is artificial, with no explanation given about why it would hold.

Answer (score 1):

I'll use the notation in the references, thus the question's `privkey1`, `privkey2`, `nonce1`, `nonce2` are noted $x_1$, $x_2$, $k_1$, $k_2$; and the prime order of curve [secp256k1](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.4.1) is noted $p$ (rather than the usual $n$).

The question mentions *"(…) 4 transactions for 2 pubkeys with the same r1 and r2"*, but gives different values for `r1` and `r2`. I'll read instead: 4 [ECDSA](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsection.4.1) signatures matching 2 private/public keys pairs using only 2 nonces, in the following arrangement:

| hash | nonce | privkey | signature | equation$\pmod p$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $h_1$ | $k_1$ | $x_1$ | $(r_1,s_1)$ | $s_1k_1≡r_1x_1+h_1$ |
| $h_2$ | $k_1$ | $x_2$ | $(r_1,s_2)$ | $s_2k_1≡r_1x_2+h_2$ |
| $h_3$ | $k_2$ | $x_1$ | $(r_2,s_3)$ | $s_3k_2≡r_2x_1+h_3$ |
| $h_4$ | $k_2$ | $x_2$ | $(r_2,s_4)$ | $s_4k_2≡r_2x_2+h_4$ |

The numbers given for $x_i$, $k_i$, $r_i$, $h_j$, $s_j$ for $i\in\{1,2\}$ and $j\in\{1,2,3,4\}$ all are in $(1,p)$; verify the equations; and $r_i$ is the function of $k_i$ prescribed by ECDSA on secp256k1, that is $r_i$ is the X coordinate of $k_i\,G$ reduced modulo $p$ (the reduction seldom makes a difference, and this is no exception).

But contrary to the references, it holds $s_1s_4≡s_2s_3\pmod p$. That prevents applying the method in the references to find $x_1$ and $x_2$, which requires that $r_1r_2(s_1s_4-s_2s_3)$ be invertible modulo $p$.

Under the assumption $h_1$, $h_2$, $h_3$, $h_4$ (or the corresponding signed messages) and $x_1$, $x_2$, $k_1$, $k_2$ are arbitrary, with the signatures derived from that, there is no reason $s_1s_4≡s_2s_3\pmod p$ would hold. That it holds makes the system of 4 equations with 4 unknowns $x_1$, $x_2$, $k_1$, $k_2$ impossible to solve from the signatures and hashes alone; we'd need some additional relation involving at least one of the unknowns $x_1$, $x_2$, $k_1$, $k_2$, but none is stated.

One possibility is that there's none to be found. The whole thing could be a decoy, a joke, perhaps a scam (which that [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/225514) suggests). One way to build the question's numbers would be that $s_4$ is computed as $s_1^{-1}\,s_2\,s_3\bmod p$, then $h_4$ is computed from $s_4$ rather than as the hash of some message.

Comment: unfornatelly it is not joke. I ask for this becouse it is solvable but I do not know how. There is a person which wants a lot money for "calculation", I tested him, and always he gave me right values of privatekeys, the one test was example which I put here . and I really don't know how he can calculate. Of course I have no money to buy from he.

Comment: @Ironic: If the test data in the question was all generated by you, please explain how that was (or better, make new test data where everything arbitrary is the SHA-256 hash of a distinct stated 1-byte input). Until you do, my opinion is that whoever generated that test data (or part thereof) is gaming or being gamed.